# Execute MySql query from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

Why wont this command execute properly:

```
    using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Update jobs SET poster_email = '@1', url = '@2' WHERE company = '@3'; ", myConn))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", email);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", url);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", company);
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

But when I substitute @3 with an actual value it works:

```
using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Update jobs SET poster_email = '@1', url = '@2' WHERE company = 'MyCompany'; ", myConn))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", email);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", url);

    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The value being passed in for the company variable is identical to the value that is hardcoded in the second example. I've stepped through with the debugger to make sure the company variable is being added as a parameter and that it's the value that I'm expecting. ie. with no spaces and trim()

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**

This also works, but then I have to worry about Sql Injection...

```
    string myQuery = string.Format("Update jobs SET poster_email = '{0}', url = '{1}' WHERE company = '{2}'; ", email, url, company);

    using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(myQuery, myConn))
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe for MySQL commands you want to use a "?" instead of a "@" :

```
using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("Update jobs SET poster_email = '?1', url = '?2' WHERE company = '?3'; ", myConn))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?1", email);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?2", url);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?3", company);
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters